# zombie.js call stack size exceeded when parsing html with jQuery

Tags: jquery, node.js, zombie.js

I've been getting the error: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" when working with the nodejs package "zombie" and jQuery. I've distilled the code as much as possible to recreate the error.

Here is a file zombie.js that can be run with nodejs using the command "node zombie.js":

```
var Browser = require("zombie");
browser = new Browser();
browser.visit("http://localhost:8000/background.html", function(error) {
    console.log("error: " + error);
});
```

and here is background.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var source = "<html><body>Hello, world!</body></html>";
  source = $(source);
</script>
```

The error happens with the line:

```
source = $(source);
```

What could be causing this? How can I fix it?

EDIT:
As suggested by P.scheit, I tried running with debug enabled, and a few lines of output to show where in the program it was. Here is the output:

```
Zombie: Opened window http://localhost:8000/background.html 
Zombie: GET http://localhost:8000/background.html => 200
Zombie: Loaded document http://localhost:8000/background.html
Zombie: GET http://localhost:8000/jquery.min.js => 200
Before the line: var source = "<html><body>Hello, world!</body></html>";
After the line: var source = "<html><body>Hello, world!</body></html>";
Before the line: source = $(source);
Maximum call stack size exceeded undefined
error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
Zombie: Event loop is empty
```

EDIT 2:

I ran node with the `--trace` option, and it looks like this is what is happening over and over until the call stack size is too big:

```
39:  HTML5Parser.phases.base.processEndTag+23(this=0x308bc44a629 <an Object>, 0x308bc456959 <String[4]: html>) {
40:   HTML5Parser.phases.inBody.endTagHtml+23(this=0x308bc44a629 <an Object>, 0x308bc456959 <String[4]: html>) {
41:    HTML5Parser.phases.inBody.endTagBody+23(this=0x308bc44a629 <an Object>, 0x308bc456959 <String[4]: html>) {
42:     HTML5Parser.phases.base.inScope+27(this=0x308bc44a629 <an Object>, 0xf26eb08fd29 <String[4]: body>, 0x15b97b404121 <undefined>) {
43:      +27(this=0x308bc43eb71 <JS Object>, 0x15b97b404121 <undefined>) {
44:       toUpperCase+38(this=0xf26eb08fc21 <String[3]: div>) {
44:       } -> 0x308bc4573c9 <String[3]: DIV>
44:       +20(this=0x308bc43eb71 <JS Object>, 0x15b97b404121 <undefined>) {
45:        toUpperCase+38(this=0xf26eb08fc21 <String[3]: div>) {
45:        } -> 0x308bc4573e9 <String[3]: DIV>
44:       } -> 0x308bc4573e9 <String[3]: DIV>
43:      } -> 0x308bc4573c9 <String[3]: DIV>
43:      +27(this=0x308bc43eb71 <JS Object>, 0x15b97b404121 <undefined>) {
44:       toUpperCase+38(this=0xf26eb08fc21 <String[3]: div>) {
44:       } -> 0x308bc457409 <String[3]: DIV>
44:       +20(this=0x308bc43eb71 <JS Object>, 0x15b97b404121 <undefined>) {
45:        toUpperCase+38(this=0xf26eb08fc21 <String[3]: div>) {
45:        } -> 0x308bc457429 <String[3]: DIV>
44:       } -> 0x308bc457429 <String[3]: DIV>
43:      } -> 0x308bc457409 <String[3]: DIV>
43:      toLowerCase+38(this=0x308bc457409 <String[3]: DIV>) {
43:      } -> 0x308bc457449 <String[3]: div>
43:      +27(this=0x308bc43eb71 <JS Object>, 0x15b97b404121 <undefined>) {
44:       toUpperCase+38(this=0xf26eb08fc21 <String[3]: div>) {
44:       } -> 0x308bc457469 <String[3]: DIV>
44:       +20(this=0x308bc43eb71 <JS Object>, 0x15b97b404121 <undefined>) {
45:        toUpperCase+38(this=0xf26eb08fc21 <String[3]: div>) {
45:        } -> 0x308bc457489 <String[3]: DIV>
44:       } -> 0x308bc457489 <String[3]: DIV>
43:      } -> 0x308bc457469 <String[3]: DIV>
43:      toLowerCase+38(this=0x308bc457469 <String[3]: DIV>) {
43:      } -> 0x308bc4574a9 <String[3]: div>
43:      indexOf+51(this=0x308bc9a79a1 <JS Array[17]>, 0x308bc4574a9 <String[3]: div>, 0x15b97b404121 <undefined>) {
44:       UseSparseVariant+38(this=0x15b97b404121 <undefined>, 0x308bc9a79a1 <JS Array[17]>, 17, 0x15b97b404141 <true>) {
44:       } -> 0x15b97b404161 <false>
43:      } -> -1
42:     } -> 0x15b97b404161 <false>
42:     Parser.parse_error+23(this=0x308bc43f769 <an HTML5Parser>, 0xa03be62aab9 <String[18]: unexpected-end-tag>, 0x308bc4574c9 <an Object>) {
42:     } -> 0x15b97b404121 <undefined>
41:    } -> 0x15b97b404121 <undefined>
41:    HTML5Parser.phases.base.processEndTag+23(this=0x308bc44a629 <an Object>, 0x308bc456959 <String[4]: html>) {
42:     HTML5Parser.phases.inBody.endTagHtml+23(this=0x308bc44a629 <an Object>, 0x308bc456959 <String[4]: html>) {
43:      HTML5Parser.phases.inBody.endTagBody+23(this=0x308bc44a629 <an Object>, 0x308bc456959 <String[4]: html>) {
44:       HTML5Parser.phases.base.inScope+27(this=0x308bc44a629 <an Object>, 0xf26eb08fd29 <String[4]: body>, 0x15b97b404121 <undefined>) {
```

As you can see, this is a loop that ends in the call stack being 5 deeper. This repeats thousands of times until the call stack size is too big.

Comment: There's gotta be more to that -- there is no call stack just for creating a jQuery object

Comment: I fixed the language a little in my question. The nodejs package "zombie" is a headless browser, which I'm guessing is causing the problem somehow.

Comment: give as second parameter to visit() the object: { debug: true } and investigate the output from zombie

Comment: Ah, thank you for this. I tried this, and added the output above.

Comment: Upon further testing, and looking at the trace, it appears it has a problem with the closing html tag. If I remove it, the error does not occur. Tested with jQuery 1.11.1, 2.0.3, and 2.1.1